# Why is Fur Elise so heavy?

Tags: musical-forms

Fur Elise is a bagatelle, which means it should be light, lovely and mild. However, the second and third movement of Fur Elise isn't light at all. Why is it?

Answer (score 4):

Definitions of the word "bagatelle" in music vary, but the only thing they agree on is that the music is brief. The definition in https://www.classical-music.com/features/articles/what-bagatelle/ does not indicate that a bagatelle has to be light at all.

And I don't think Liszt's *Bagatelle sans tonalité* sounds distinctively light, either.

So since bagatelles don't have to be light, "Für Elise" doesn't always have to be, either.

Comment: And aren't bridges often darker than verses and choruses, to mark the contrast?

Answer (score 2):

This is really subjective, but I don't think it's a "heavy" piece. The moto is just a turn figure and brief. The second interlude is dramatic, but neither ponderous nor profound. It's sort of like the bad guy tying a lady to the railroad tracks in a silent movie.

Answer (score 2):

The moodiness of "Für Elise" may well stem from a failed love affair.

Maynard Solomon, in his Beethoven biography, writes:

> Beethoven's courtship of Therese Malfatti was a hopeless one -- opposed by her parents, conducted through an unwilling intermediary ..., and without the slightest encouragement from the intended bride. ... The courtship had probably run its course by the spring of 1810.<sup>1</sup>

And in an accompanying footnote...

> The Bagatelle in A minor, WoO 59, known as "Für Elise" and composed in either 1808 or 1810, is thought to have been written for Therese Malfatti.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Maynard Solomon, 2001, *Beethoven*, 2nd revised edition (Schirmer Trade Books), 201-02.

<sup>2</sup> Ibid., 458n58.